# Odd Output with Rails each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that for some reason displays the memory location of the object I'm trying to loop through.  I'm kinda new at rails, so I'm unsure why this is happening.  The object is a note with two fields, title and content.

In the controller I have (in the index function)

```
@note = Note.all
```

Then in the view I'm doing this

```
<%= @notes.each do |note| %>
    <%= link_to note.title, "notes/#{note.id}"%>
<% end %>
```

The output in the browser is 
`School Work #Note:0x1042e4708>#Note:0x1042e2ae8>`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rather than:

```
<%= @notes.each do |note| %>
```

use:

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
```

wrapping ruby in `<%=%>` will always output something to the view, drop the equal sign (`<%%>`) to simply execute ruby without outputting